# opencsv read from an unknow line but known word?

Tags: java, csv, opencsv

Ok, i have a csv file:

```
Summary
    heading1,heading2,heading3
    value1,value2,value2
    value1,value2,value2
    value1,value2,value2
    value1,value2,value2
Detail
    heading11,heading12,heading13
    value1,value2,value2
    value1,value2,value2
    value1,value2,value2
    value1,value2,value2
```

I'm using the com.opencsv.CSVReader library.

I need to read from the line "Detail", however I don't know which row it is, because there can be an undefined amount of rows before it. Summary starts from
row 13, but I know how to work with that.

Is there an easy mode for opencsv to find the row "Detail" and start from there? 
Or do i need to somehow count the rows before Detail and pass it into OPENCSV as a parameter?

Comment: Your file is not going to be a valid CSV. There is no official definition, but if we consider [RFC 4180](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4180) as one, it is not possible to divide the document in parts like you do. Best option is to look for Detail yourself, extract the subsequent rows and see if you can parse those as a CSV, or to divide eveything in separate files.

Comment: @bracco23 well, I didn't create the CSV, Amazon did. They call this as a CSV.

Comment: Taking a look at the documentation of [CSVReader](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/apidocs/index.html), it takes as an input a standard Reader, so you can read each line, match against a regex to find the line with "Detail", and after that read the subsequent lines into a string and use a StringReader to feed them to the CSVReader

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since dividing a CSV into sections is not a common requirement and not necessarily supported by the library, you should find yourself the point where the rows you are interested in start and extract them. One way could be:

```
BufferedReader b = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(source));
String line = b.readLine();
StringBuilder build = new StringBuilder();
while(line != null && !line.equals("Detail")){
    line = b.readLine();
}
line = b.readLine();
while(line != null){
    build.append(line);
    build.append('\n');
    line = b.readLine();
}
System.out.println(build.toString());
Reader toBeParsed = new StringReader(build.toString());
```

Which basically reads the file until a line matching the Detail part is found then adds all the remaining rows into a String. From this string a reader is used that can be fed into CSVReader.

I assume that all the remaining rows must be considered ( consider to match against another string to stop that if that's not the case), and that the line where to start is exactly "Detail" (you can use a regex for a more flexible approach)

[Here is a live demo](https://ideone.com/BqiZIw)

Comment: Thanks, I think i'll take a similar approach.